# What is the process to create a table with PHP and mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to connect to my data base and create a table through PHP but with no lucky.

I tried to connect with `$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $passwd, $schema);` in the file `db_inc_oop.php` and then run in web browser `localhost:8080/orders.php` that is the PHP to create the table. I put 8080 in the port because i'm using XAMPP and the port configured is 8080.

This is **db_inc_oop.php** file:

```
 <?php

 /* Host name of the MySQL server */
 $host = 'localhost';

 /* MySQL account username */
 $user = 'myUser';

 /* MySQL account password */
 $passwd = 'kpesao123';

 /* The schema you want to use */
 $schema = 'mySchema';

 /* Connection with MySQLi, OOP-style */
 $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $passwd, $schema);

 /* Check if the connection succeeded */
 if (!is_null($mysqli->connect_error))
  {
    echo 'Connection failed<br>';
    echo 'Error number: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . '<br>';
    echo 'Error message: ' . $mysqli->connect_error . '<br>';
    die();
  }

  echo 'Successfully connected!<br>';
```

And in the **orders.php** file I write

```
 <?php

 /* Include the MySQLi oop-style syntax connection script */
 include 'db_inc_oop.php';
```

I expect to connect to my database and then create a table through PHP.

Comment: when you run your file in browser i.e localhost:8080/orders.php do you get printed Successfully connected! in you web page screen?

Comment: It would really help us if you explained what your _issue_ with the code is? What actually happens? What problem are you asking us to help you with? Where's the SQL-code for creating the tables? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hello and welcome to `SO`. What have you tried for creating table??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in orders.php

write below code

```
<?php

include 'db_inc_oop.php';

$sql = "CREATE TABLE orders (
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(50),
  order_date TIMESTAMP
)";
if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
  echo "Table orders created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($mysqli);
}
```

Try this it will create orders table in your database but before that make sure you cave given create table permission to the user which you have used to connect to database

hope this will help you and this is what you expecting

Comment: i wrote the code that you indicated and when i enter localhost:8080/orders.php in my webrowser, indicates the next error:

Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in /opt/lampp/htdocs/orders.php on line 12


Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/orders.php on line 12


Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in /opt/lampp/htdocs/orders.php on line 15


Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/orders.php on line 15

Error creating table:

I checked the code but i couldn't find the error

Comment: When you hit url in browser did you get the message successfully connected?

Comment: No, i didn't receive the message of succesfully connected

Comment: But i checked the credentials to access to database and seems to be ok